# ProxyPass exception gives me "too many redirects" error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have an application on my server that is for the most part overwriting Apache. Now I want to install PhpMyAdmin on my VPS, it doesn't work (displays directory listing instead of UI), but by asking around on few sites plus some trial and error I realized I'm trying to run PhpMyAdmin through my application (Traccar) instead through Apache.

Now back to the topic. I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I have the following site configuration:

```
Listen 80
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName x.example.com
        Redirect / https://x.example.com
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName x.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost

        ProxyPass /api/socket ws://localhost:app_port/api/socket
        ProxyPassReverse /api/socket ws://localhost:app_port/api/socket

        ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:app_port/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:app_port/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +StrictRequire
        SSLProtocol TLSv1
        ServerAlias x.example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The way I want it to work:

If I connect to **x.example.com** I get redirected to my application. Works properly.

If I connect to **x.example.com/phpmyadmin** I want to receive PhpMyAdmin UI. I receive a "too many redirects" error instead.

When I access phpmyadmin directory the rewrite log keeps alternating between these two messages in the server log:

```
[Fri May 10 10:32:38.733370 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 19228] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [x.example.com/sid#7f34cd331cc0][rid#7f34cd2640a0/initial] pass through /phpmyadmin
[Fri May 10 10:32:38.767398 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 19228] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [x.example.com/sid#7f34cd331cc0][rid#7f34cd2620a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /phpmyadmin
```

This is what I receive when I wget to **x.example.com/phpmyadmin**:

```
--2019-05-10 10:43:19--  https://x.example.com/phpmyadmin
Resolving x.example.com (x.example.com)... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to x.example.com (x.example.com)|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://x.example.com/phpmyadmin [following]
--2019-05-10 10:43:19--  https://x.example.com/phpmyadmin
Reusing existing connection to x.example.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://x.example.com/phpmyadmin [following]
--2019-05-10 10:43:19--  https://x.example.com/phpmyadmin
Reusing existing connection to x.example.com:443.
```

The lines repeat until they reach 20 redirections.

If I curl to **x.example.com/phpmyadmin** I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The document has moved <a href="https://x.example.comphpmyadmin">here</a>.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at x.example.com Port 80</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the server logs for more detail on what is causing the redirects. (On a side note, consider running phpMyAdmin on its own subdomain rather where you can more easily implement additional access controls as well. ).

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to do it until tomorrow. I hope it won't be too late for a response.

Comment: Where do I look for logs? I looked at apache logs and in "other_vhosts_access" I found over 10 "GET /phpmyadmin" connections in the exact same second. It's definitely me, although this error log doesn't tell me much about what I could be doing wrong

Comment: up the tracing of mod_rewrite and look in the error log of apache. Your ProxyPass exclusion should be good, but maybe you have a rewrite alternating between directory with slash and without.

Comment: @user188737 When I access phpmyadmin directory the rewrite log keeps alternating between these two messages: https://pastebin.com/puL56qQL

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information, don't use comments (I did this for you for now). Regarding the question, a redirect loop with a proxy configuration is usually a wrong baseurl configured in the backend server.

Comment: Run a request to `/phpmyadmin/` with wget/curl and check where you are redirected.

Comment: This is what I receive when I wget to my to my website /phpmyadmin: https://pastebin.com/JJ0rXjB6. The lines repeat themselves until they reach 20 redirects.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider What you may find interesting is if I curl to x.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin I receive this: https://pastebin.com/1WSarVQA. Notice how phpmyadmin misses a / before it, maybe this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: What's even more interesting is that the response comes from Apache itself. Since you have not configured any redirects in that virtualhost there must be something configured in other parts of the Apache config that you are not showing to us.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider is there a specific config file I should post? Most of my configs are pretty much default...

Comment: Somehow the Redirect / rule on port 80 is also working on port 443? That would be consistent with what you are seeing. It is slightly off also, it should be `Redirect / https://x.example.com/`

Comment: I just remembered something stupid. I forgot back when I started installing the SSL certificate I didn't know very well what I was doing, my redirects wouldn't work etc. Basically I forgot I left a permament redirect rule in my apache2.conf - this caused an infinite loop. Deleting that line from apache config fixed my problem. Thanks to everyone involved.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it ... otherwise the question will pop up again and again in the future because it isn't answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is incredibly simple.
I forgot I left a permament redirect rule in my apache2.conf - this caused the infinite loop. Deleting that line from apache config fixed my problem. Thanks to everyone involved.